# Thinking in Laravel query building?

Tags: orm, laravel-5, eloquent

I'd like to know what are the best practice process to device a Laravel query.
By build I mean:
1) solve the problem as SQL first
2) then write the code as Laravel queries
3) rewrite the code as Laravel eloquent relationships
Are my habits ok, or where do I need to improve in order to fully grasp Laravel's ORM ?

Comment: what exactly you want to ask , as this is totally a personal choice, you can use ORM or you can just use mysql queries in `DB::raw()` its just your pick. using ORM is good of you want to make your code cleaner and understandable to other devs.

Comment: Lets say it's decided to use ORM everywhere, what would be the thinking process here in order to develop the full picture of how the code should work ?

Comment: Depends on your expertise on using eloquent ORM.. since it is very easy and straightforward.. so you just need to understand it properly.. or you can write sql query first and then write that query in ORM way.. in eloquent there is a function `toSql()` to display orm query in MySQL format. So you can compare if you are writing correct query or not.

Comment: How to train more my eloquent ORM expertise :) ?

Comment: Start working on it